# How CXF redirects non-matching HTTP Request to default HTML Page?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, cxf

As CXF provides configuration to set welcome default page from :

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>static-welcome-file</param-name>
            <param-value>/main.html</param-value>
</init-param>
```

This is working fine.

My question : **How CXF(org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController) redirect non-matching http request to a static HTML page  ?**

I also tried this - but no luck :

```
<init-param>
            <param-name>redirects-list</param-name>
            <param-value>/main.html</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>redirect-attributes</param-name>
            <param-value>javax.servlet.include.request_uri</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>redirect-servlet-name</param-name>
            <param-value>default</param-value>
</init-param>
```